# Covariance of an uncertain vector going through an uncertain transformation

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix

> Let's have two vectors $\mathbf \omega \in \mathbb R^3$, $\mathbf \theta \in \mathbb R^3$ and their associated covariance, $\Sigma_{\omega} \in \mathbb R^{3\times3}$ and $\Sigma_{\theta} \in \mathbb R^{3\times3}$ respectively. A function $\mathbf{R}(\cdot): \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ defined as :
>
> $$\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{x})=\: \mathbf{I}_{3} \:+ \: \sin \left \| \mathbf{x} \right \| \left [ \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\left \| \mathbf{x} \right \|} \right ]_{\times} \:+ \: (1-\cos \left \| \mathbf{x} \right \|) \left [ \frac{\mathbf{x}}{\left \| \mathbf{x} \right \|} \right ]_{\times}$$
>
> with $\left [\cdot \right ]_{\times} $ the "[cross product matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication)". (Function **R** is known as [Rodrigues' formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) for 3D rotations).
>
> Given that $\mathbf{\alpha}= \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{\theta})\,*\,\mathbf \omega$, $\mathbf \;\alpha \in \mathbb R^3$,  **what is the covariance of $\mathbf{\alpha}$**,  $\:\Sigma_{\mathbf{\alpha}}$?

I'm a bit puzzled on how to handle this problem. Shoud I introduce little perturbations and come back to the very definition of the covariance? In that case, how do I compute $E[\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}]$?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Because$$\alpha:\mathbb{R}^6 \approx\mathbb{R}^3\otimes \mathbb{R}^3 \to \operatorname{Mat}(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)\approx\mathbb{R}^9,$$and--assuming your vectors are uncorrelated--the covariance is$$\operatorname{Cov}(\omega,\theta)=\Sigma=\pmatrix{\Sigma_\omega&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}&\Sigma_\theta},$$this is a standard instance of a differentiable map $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and, assuming $\left\|\mathbf{x}\right\|$ has little chance of being near $0$ and $\Sigma$ is small, apply the usual [delta method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22delta+method%22) machinery.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung This question doesn't look like the kind of routine exercise we would treat as self-study.

Comment: Thanks a lot @whuber for you answer. I'm a bit puzzled because $\alpha$ is a vector of dimension 3x1 resulting of the matrix operation $\mathbf{R} * \omega$. Therefore, its covariance should be a 3x3 matrix.

This problem is not self-study as I encounter it while propagating covariances of the angular speed of a robot joint to other frames.

Comment: That's right.  I was thinking of your function $R$ instead of $\alpha.$  The image of $\alpha$ is indeed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its covariance will be a $3\times 3$ matrix.  But the general point still holds and it appears the delta method is what you are looking for.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a shot. If I succeed, I'll come post the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is not as complicated as it seems.

On a general basis, given a function $ f: \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^m$ and its associated covariance $\Sigma_{\mathbf x} \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$, if $\mathbf y = f(\mathbf x)$ then:

$$\Sigma_{\mathbf y} \simeq \left . \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf x}\right |_{\mathbf x} \Sigma_{\mathbf x} \left . \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf x}\right |_{\mathbf x} ^\intercal$$

Here our function $f$ is a vectorized version of the Rodrigues' formulae of 3D rotation. The Jacobians can be a bit tedious to compute by hand, hence I used a software to analytically derive the equation.